# Dimension default members not getting displayed in MDX Filters on Reporting tool

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

We have a Cube where we got a dimension called - "Report Currency". Default member is set as - [Report Currency].&[0].

Now if I create a filter of "Report Currency" on MS Excel based on the cube, I get to see 5 currencies (EUR/GBP/JPY/USD/CHF). But while I create an MDX filter on IcCube Reporting tool, I am getting to see only - 4 currencies (EUR/GBP/JPY/USD/CHF). 'EUR' is not getting displayed.

What do we require to do so that we are able to view all the 5 currencies on on the MDX filter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch on the "Add Default Member" option as seen in the following picture:

[image: filter]